# Quando eu tento jogar o repositório da minha máquina no repositório do Google cloud eu recebo um erro dizendo : remote origin já existe

Tags: git, git-remote

Tenho uma aplicação já criada, estou usando o Google cloud e também tenho um repositório no github.

Quando eu tento jogar o repositório da minha máquina no repositório do Google cloud eu recebo um erro dizendo:

> ```
> remote origin já existe.
> ```

Como posso resolver isso?

```
1.{   dimal@DESKTOP-00VTGS0 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/api-rest (initial)
-----> essa é minha branch   } 
2.{   $ git remote add origin 35.199.127.153:repo-api
-----> esse é meu comando    }
3.{   fatal: remote origin already exists.
-----> esse é o erro         }
```

Comment: `remote add` serve para adicionar nas suas configurações um repositório remoto, vc passa um nome qualquer e a URL dele (no caso, o nome que vc deu é "origin" e a URL é "35.199.etc...". O erro só diz que já existe um remoto nas suas configurações chamado "origin" - vc pode ver qual é a URL dele com `git remote show origin` (ou `git remote -v` para mostrar todos os remotos), se for a URL que vc quer, já está tudo certo. Se não for a URL que vc quer, adicione ele com outro nome diferente de "origin"

Answer (score 0):

Isso se dá porque já existe um remoto com o nome `origin`. Você pode simplesmente trocar a URL do remoto usando:

```
git remote set-url origin <sua-url>
```

Veja também a documentação do [git-remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-urlem).